# I want to add a view that will persist through out the application?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I want to add a view that will persist through out the application?
How can i achieve this?

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    [self.window addSubview:myView];
```

This is not working.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need subclass of `UIViewController` with view, set it as `rootViewController` for window and it will be persist

Comment: Your above code will works fine, But you should avoid the hard-coding like y = 430. Because iPhone 4 and 5 will have different heights. Also, If you want to see your "myView" on your current view controller. You should set your current view controller's view color as clear color.

Comment: i want it for all screen based on some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways in achieving that. It's not clear if you want a *view like that* be in each view controller, or you want *the same instance* in each view controller.

Since I don't see any reason to have one shared instance (basing on your description), my approach would be to subclass `UIViewController`, let's call it `SOMyViewController`, and then inherit all view controllers in your app from `SOMyViewController`.

Then, I'd override the 'viewDidLoad' method of `SOMyViewController` as follows:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self addMyCustomView]) {
        UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
        myView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
        [self.window addSubview:myView];    
    }
}

/**
 Override this in all your subclasses to decide whether to display the custom view or not
 */
- (BOOL) addMyCustomView {
    return YES;
}
```

If instead you want *the same instance* shared among view controllers, I would change the above code as follows:

```
static UIView *mySharedView;

+ (void) initialize {
    mySharedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
    mySharedView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self addMyCustomView]) {
        [self.window addSubview:mySharedView];    
    }
}

/**
 Override this in all your subclasses to decide whether to display the custom view or not
 */
- (BOOL) addMyCustomView {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: ,i want to know how you gonna use it by declaring the view in appdelegate and then use that from some other class...

Comment: If you mean having one app wide instance, all you have to do is inherit your view controllers from `SOMyViewController`. If you use the 2nd block of code, you see that the `UIView` is declared as static, and initialized once in the `initialize` method. There's no need to use appdelegate

Comment: Yeah you are right,i did that in a same way ,i added the view on window.

Comment: i need further help,i mean i want to show the created view with some animation...

Comment: I think you have to experiment with animation, and if you encounter any problem or stuck doing a specific thing just post another question here. I think animation is outside the scope of this question. There are a lot of tutorials, a good starting point might be raywenderlich.com